# update tab bar height in iOS 7/8 from iOS 6 - UITabBar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6, uitabbar

I am updating an app that was written for previous iOS (5/6). I have updated the icons for the tab bar; according to the Apple requirements ([Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)) they are 50x50p for all devices except the iphone 6 plus. Unfortunately also my tab bar is 49 pixels in height (keep still the iOS6 size) and the icons cover its entire space. This tab bar (UITabBar) was created in the Interface builder but I am not able to change "size inspector" values.
iOS 6/7 Deltas values don't do anything.

I have setted the Deployment Target to iOS 7.1 and Base SDK to 8.0

How can i change/increase the tab bar height like in iOS 7/8?