# xcode custom tab bar 1 pixel gap at top

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tabs

I am currently updating some old Xcode apps in Xcode 6.

I have a custom tab bar, that used to load and look fine, but in Xcode 6 it has developed a 1px gap at the top of the tab bar that I am unable to get rid of, and it looks really bad!

I have read some other similar SO posts and followed all suggestions, but none of them seem to have any effect, and the 1px gap is still there.

[image]

Here is my custom tab bar code:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGRect tabbarTopFrame = CGRectMake(0,(screenSize.height - 59),320,10);
UIImageView *tabbarTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:tabbarTopFrame];
tabbarTop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_top.png"];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:tabbarTop];

UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_introduction_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_introduction_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_nests_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_nests_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_home_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_home_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_dogowners_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_dogowners_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_spotted_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_spotted_default.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setClipsToBounds:YES];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

item0.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item4.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);

[item0 setImage:[unselectedImage0 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item1 setImage:[unselectedImage1 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item2 setImage:[unselectedImage2 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item3 setImage:[unselectedImage3 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item4 setImage:[unselectedImage4 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

[item0 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage0 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item1 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage1 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item2 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage2 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item3 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage3 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item4 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage4 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

The images were all used in the previous app code, that was written in Xcode 4, and all worked fine then, so it must be something that has changed in Xcode 5 or 6, or in iOS7/iOS8?

Comment: The code assumes that tab bar height is 49, is it true? You can check the tab bar height through code.

Comment: yes, if I do a code check for the tabbar height, it returns 49px. All the graphics are confirmed as 49px high. My custom tab bar is 59px high, with 49px for the tabs, and a 10px top graphic. This extra 1px gap sits between the 49px tab bar and the 10px top part.

Comment: Can't reproduce, it might be something with tabbarTop image, try to change it to another image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not the same issue, something in this SO post ([update tab bar height in iOS 7/8 from iOS 6 - UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218094/update-tab-bar-height-in-ios-7-8-from-ios-6-uitabbar)) helped me.

Turns out I didn't make any changes to any of my code at all - but just changing the heights of the graphics from 49px to 50px high solved the problem.

Odd.